# How to query raster in PostGIS within GeoJSON mask only

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a raster in PostGIS which I need to query pixel values from, but only within a specific area. So I have a GeoJSON polygon within which I want to extract min/max/avg values of the raster from.

The raster is divided into 640 `rid's` as well, due to pretiling. How can I combine the values?

So, how can I do this?

Comment: I would start by converting the GeoJSON to a geometry. Afaik, tiling will have no impact, assuming it is all one logical raster, other than speeding it up.